# Setter of a Container ViewModel class property that is dependent on another property of Contained ViewModel class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Please have a look at the following code

```
public class VM1
{
    private bool isValid;
    private VM2 vmInstance;

    // ...

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return this.isValid; }
        set { /* ... */ } 
    }

    public VM2 VMInstance
    {
        // ...
    }

}
public class VM2
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now the `IsValid`-property of `VM1` is dependent on the value of the `IsValid`-property of `VM2`. What is the best way to achieve that?

I have found a way to solve my problem.
VM1 class subscribes to propertychanged event of VM2.
and whenevr ISValid property of VM2 is changed, In this eventhandler, we call setState()
method of VM1 to decide the value of IsValid property.

```
    void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "IsValid":
                // call a method in VM1 to decide the value of IsValid property of VM1
                // say, the method name is setState()
                break;
         }
     }
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: When you say "VM1 is dependent on value of IsValid property of VM2", you mean something like `return isValid && vmInstance != null && vmInstance.IsValid;`?

Comment: Have you thought about exposing your VM2 IsValid property in VM1 creating just a getter like: `public bool IsValid {get return vmInstance.IsValid; }`

Comment: Actually IsValid property of VM2 is dependent on various other properties of VM2. And IsValid property of VM1 is dependent on 2 other propertis of VM1 (say Prop1,Prop2) and also on the value of IsValid property of VM2. ISValid property of VM1 is true only if Prop1( type is string) is not empty and Prop2 (type is int) is greater than 18 and IsValid property of VM2 is true.

Answer (score 0):

I'll need more information on how you're going to consider the `VM2`'s `IsValid` property.

You can start with passing an instance of `VM2` into the constructor of `VM1` so that it may be referenced.  Look at the following example.

```
public class VM1
{
    private bool isValid;
    private VM2 vmInstance;
    //......

    public VM1(VM2 vm2)
    {
        VMInstance = vm2;
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isValid && VMInstance.IsValid;
        }
        set
        {
            // 
        }

    }

    public VM2 VMInstance 
    { 
        get { return vmInstance; }
        set { vmInstance = value; }
    }
}

public class VM2
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check `VMInstance` for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If `VM1` is only valid if `VM2`is valid, too, use the `&&`-operator to return common result of both `IsValid`-properties:

```
public class VM1
{
    // ...

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        { 
            return isValid && 
                   (VMInstance != null && VMInstance.IsValid);
        }
        set
        {
            isValid = value;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Thus `VM1.IsValid` will only return `true` if both `VM1.isValid` (the private field) and
`VM2.IsValid` return `true`.

It is up to you to decide whether `VM1.IsValid` will return `true` or `false` depending on whether `VMInstance` is `null` or not - just adjust the statement accordingly.

The setter then only sets the value for the current instance, as it does not influence the `IsValid`-property of the second view model.

Comment: Don't forget to check `VMInstance` for `null`.

Comment: And you might drop all the `this.` stuff as it is redundant.

Comment: @Clemens right again. But that's coding guideline in my current work - so I just type that out of a habit ;)